# optional where clause condition in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am working on a project where I load a list of students depending on the date selected and the teacher chosen from a dropdown.The list contains those students data whose class teacher is the teacher selected. Now i am using the following query:

```
select s.studentcode,s.studentname,a.attdate,if(a.period='01' or 
a.period='AM',a.status,'') as attAM,if(a.period='PM',a.status,'') as attPM 
from tblstudent s left join tblattendance a on s.studentcode=a.studentcode 
where s.classcode='10002' and a.attdate='2014-04-11'
```

Now the problem with the above is query is that if i chose some date like 2014-04-15 then as attendance is not marked for this date then no record is found,but i want that the student list is always displayed and if attendance is marked for that date it should be displayed accordingly else those fields will be blank

[image]

The above screenshot is displaying the list which I want.Now the field AM should be blank if attendance for that date is not marked and if it is marked it should contain the corresponding attendance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `AND a.attdate = '2014-04-11'` to join's ON() clause so if date is not present it still returns the records for `s.classcode = '10002'` and `a.attdate` column will be null in the result set,where filter is applied to whole resultset where as using additional condition in join will filter the records from right table i.e `tblattendance` not on whole resultset

```
SELECT 
  s.studentcode,
  s.studentname,
  a.attdate,
  IF(
    a.period = '01' 
    OR a.period = 'AM',
    a.status,
    ''
  ) AS attAM,
  IF(a.period = 'PM', a.status, '') AS attPM 
FROM
  tblstudent s 
  LEFT JOIN tblattendance a 
    ON (s.studentcode = a.studentcode AND a.attdate = '2014-04-11')
WHERE s.classcode = '10002'
```

Comment: hmm,it worked thank you :).Please tell me one thing more,this means join can be done depending on this type of conditions also rather than joining on common fields

Comment: @rupinder18 Joining should be done first on basis of primary key and foreign key then if you still wants the result where your condition is not met you can place it in the on clause also see my updated answer

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Errr. Typo on `whole`.